# Last record in database is being used rather than the record desired

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, forms

I have an approval/denial user system that I created and I am running into an issue with it.

I first have to approve or deny the user. If that user is approved, their name is placed into a different section of the page called 'Approved Users'. Within this area I change the user's permission/group level. However, if I have more than one user in the approved user section, if I try to update a user, it updates the last record displayed no matter which user I try to change.

For example, if I had this and tried to update Rick's record, Bob's would be updated. Bob's record would be the last one in my database.

```
-Bob
-Tony
-Rick
```

Whenever I approve the record, the correct user's record gets changed. It is only when I try to change the group/permission part, it does not work right.

Starting here it works..

```
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
$run = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_requests ORDER BY id DESC");
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($run);

    if( $numrows ) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
            if($row['status'] == "Pending"){

                $pending_id        = $row['id'];
                $pending_user_id   = $row['user_id'];
                $pending_firstname = $row['firstname'];
                $pending_lastname  = $row['lastname'];
                $pending_username  = $row['username'];
                $pending_email  = $row['email'];
?>
        <form action="" method="POST" id="status">
             <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $pending_id; ?>' id='pending_id'/>
<?php
        if ($pending_firstname == true) {
            echo "Name - ". $pending_firstname . " " . $pending_lastname . "</br>" . 
                "Username - ". $pending_username . "</br></br>"
                //echo print_r($_POST);
?>


                        <button class="approve" type="submit" form="status" name="approve" value="<?=$pending_id;?>">Approve</button>
                        <button class="deny" type="submit" form="status" name="deny" value="<?=$pending_id;?>">Deny</button>
                        </form><br><br><br>
<?php   
                    ;} else {
                        echo "There are no Pending Requests at this time.";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
?>
<hr><br>
```

End of Pending users and up to this point it works and uses the correct user that was clicked. Now at this point when I try to update the user's info it updated the first user displayed...

```
        <h2>Approved User Requests</h2><br>
        <div id="success" style="color: red;"></div><br>
<?php
    $con2 = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
    $run2 = mysqli_query($con2,"SELECT * FROM user_requests ORDER BY id DESC");
    $runUsers2 = mysqli_query($con2,"SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC");
    $numrows2 = mysqli_num_rows($run2);

        if( $numrows2 ) {
            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run2)){
                if($row2['status'] == "Approved"){
                //var_dump ($row2);

                    $approved_id        = $row2['user_id'];
                    $approved_firstname = $row2['firstname'];
                    $approved_lastname  = $row2['lastname'];
                    $approved_username  = $row2['username'];
                    $approved_email  = $row2['email'];

        if ($approved_firstname == true) {
            echo "Name - ". $approved_firstname . " " . $approved_lastname . "</br>" . 
                "Username - ". $approved_username . "</br></br>"
?>
<div class="change_group_button"> 
     <a class="change_group" href="javascript:void(0)">Change User Permission</a>
</div><br>
<div id="light" class="change_group_popup">
    <a class="close" href="javascript:void(0)">Close</a>
 <div class="group_success" style="color: red;"></div><br>
    <form id="update_group" action="" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
       <div class="field">
        <label for="group">Group</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $approved_id; ?>" id="approved_id" name="id" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $approved_firstname; ?>" id="approved_firstname" name="firstname" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $approved_lastname; ?>" id="approved_lastname" name="lastname" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $approved_username; ?>" id="approved_username" name="username" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $approved_email; ?>" id="approved_email" name="email" />
        <select id='group_id' name='group' required>
            <option value=''><?php echo htmlentities($group); ?></option>
            <option value="1">Bench</option>
            <option value="2">Spectator</option>
            <option value="3">Team Member</option>
            <option value="4">Commissioner</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="group">
    </form>
```

AJAX that I use to update the info..

```
//AJAX call for Approving the status
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.approve').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'userRequest_approve.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: $(this).val(), //id
                status: 'Approved' //status
            },
            success: function (data) {
                //do something with the data that got returned
                $("#success").fadeIn();
                $("#success").show();
                $('#success').html('User Status Changed!');
                $('#success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
            },
            //type: 'POST'
        });
        return false;
    });
});


//AJAX call for updating the group
$(document).ready(function () {


    $('#update_group').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'user_group_update.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
            id: $("#approved_id").val(), //id
            firstname: $("#approved_firstname").val(), //firstname
            lastname: $("#approved_lastname").val(), //lastname
            username: $("#approved_username").val(), //username
            email: $("#approved_email").val(), //email
           // update_group: $("#group_id").val() //group level
          update_group: $(this).find( "#group_id option:selected" ).val()
        },
            success: function (data) {
                //do something with the data that got returned
                $(".group_success").fadeIn();
                $(".group_success").show();
                $('.group_success').html('User Permission Level Changed!');
                $('.group_success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
                alert(data);
            },
             error: function(jqXHR, textStatus,errorThrown )
            {
              // alert on an http error 
              alert( textStatus +  errorThrown );
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

I believe the entire issue has to do with the id, but I don't get what is wrong with the id I am getting. Does anyone see anything I am doing incorrectly that is causing this?

Comment: I don't see where `$group` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

In the first part of your code, I found a few syntax errors. Corrected to:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
$run = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_requests ORDER BY id DESC");
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($run);
if( $numrows ) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
        if($row['status'] == "Pending"){
            $pending_id        = $row['id'];
            $pending_user_id   = $row['user_id'];
            $pending_firstname = $row['firstname'];
            $pending_lastname  = $row['lastname'];
            $pending_username  = $row['username'];
            $pending_email     = $row['email'];
            echo "<form action='' method='POST' id='status'>\r\n";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='$pending_id' id='pending_id' />\r\n";
            if ($pending_firstname == true) {
                echo "Name - $pending_firstname $pending_lastname</br>\r\n";
                echo "Username - $pending_username</br></br>\r\n";
                echo "<button class='approve' type='submit' form='status' name='approve' value='$pending_id'>Approve</button>\r\n";
                echo "<button class='deny' type='submit' form='status' name='deny' value='$pending_id'>Deny</button>\r\n";
                echo "</form><br><br><br>\r\n"; 
            } else {
                echo "There are no Pending Requests at this time.";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Second, am concerned about your double query. I would advise running the query, iterate over the result, and then run the second query. Should also free the results after each query just to be safe. If this is in the same page, I would also not create a new connection.

If you could post any error or results form your Console, could expand upon my answer.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean in your explanation "I would advise running the query, iterate over the result, and then run the second query. Should also free the results after each query just to be safe"..... As of now, I do not have any errors. This works, but it isn't getting the correct id from the user that I click on. It is only using the first one from the database in that table.

Comment: Ok, so when you pass `id` via POST, what value is received by PHP? I also never see you call `$_POST['id']`. Also `value="<?=$pending_id;?>"` is not correct syntax. Should be `value="<?php echo $pending_id; ?>"` That was something I corrected in my code that I posted.